# How to dynamically add externally defined beans definitions to Spring context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a requirement where Spring bean definitions need to be loaded dynamically from an "external" source. This external source could be some type of file, database, or web service.

I've read up on `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` classes that can do this type of thing, but I'm running into one big challenge:

The object that retrieves the bean definiton info from the external source is configured as a bean itself (e.g. DatabaseBeanDefinitionProvider) so it would need to be configured with all dependencies (e.g. DataSource) and available from the context to fetch the data.

I'm not sure where/when in the Spring application context lifecycle to do this: essentially use "existing beans to add new beans" to the context.

Any ideas experts?

Comment: I think you will need to dynamically create and manage child contexts. There is almost no way you can add bean definitions to already initialized context (or you will need to `refresh` the context every time you modify bean definitions).

Comment: Do the beans that you'd like to add dynamically all implement a known set of interfaces?

Comment: @PavelHoral - the loading of these dynamic beans is an app initialization process, so it would only need to refresh once (I think), although I'm still a little unsure of where in the initialization to do this.

Comment: @JohnR - no unfortunately, they don't implement a common interface.

Comment: Is it the exact same type of beans that initialized each time, regardless of the source of the bean definition?  For example, do you know that you'll always have a FooService and a BarService?

Comment: @JohnR - The dynamic beans are sort of like "plugins" or "modules" for this app, so they'll be added/changed/removed periodically.

Comment: As @PavelHoral mentioned, child contexts sound like a good bet.  Have you tried/considered something [like this Spring Integration sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/ftp/DynamicFtpChannelResolver.java)?  Although it's using Spring Integration the basic principle is the same.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will look into creating a child context, although the problem I'm going to run into is that these dynamic beans may need to be available to the parent context(s) in some scenarios.

Comment: If you need to load bean definitions only once on startup (and you don't care about definition conflicts), just use `<import>` or `@Import`. Also you might want to check [`BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possibility to use a database table for loading persisted bean definitions is already implemented in Spring with the JdbcBeanDefinitionReader. I mentioned this just to be sure you do not reinvent the wheel ;). You can also use the PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader if you want to rely just on a bunch of properties from a plain file.

Both classes have the BeanDefinitionRegistry as dependency, the bucket, where all bean definitions will be collected during the bean definition load phase. Implementing the BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor (BDRPP) interface provides this in a very convenient way.

Now, how to get it running:
Basically, if you stick to the DataSource-bound way, I would recommend to setup those dependencies by hand, means instantiating the BDRPP and dependencies in an own ApplicationContextInitializer implementation. In there you can then call applicationContext.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(yourBdrpp) and load whatever properties you need for the DataSource under the JdbcBeanDefinitionReader.

XML will also work fine if all your dependencies are independent of any autowiring or properties replacement. You need to define them explicitly, e.g.

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean class="net.bensteinert.MyBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor">
    <constructor-arg ref="jdbcTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

Only problem is, that your dataSource will have no access to any property placeholder infrastructure, That is the reason why I would tend to the programmatic solution.

Means in general, no worries about using beans for creating beans. They just need to be independent. By the way, the powerful Java Config bootstrapping is also a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.

More details on dynamic bean definition can also be found here: [How to create dynamic bean definitions in Spring](http://blog.comsysto.com/2014/09/26/how-to-create-your-own-dynamic-bean-definitions-in-spring/)

A very good introduction into the Spring Bean Lifecycle can be found here: [SpringONE 2013 Presentation by Mark Secrist](http://de.slideshare.net/SpringCentral/beyond-dependencyinjection-springone2013)

Hope that helps, 
so long.